# how to write a vba with a variable within the path

Tags: vba, excel, variables, path

This is my second post on this site and an I am relatively new to VBA.

My today question is,

How can I add a cell value to the Path String to designate the folder where I would like the workbook to be saved.

```
Dim Path As String
Dim FileName1 As String
Dim FileName2 As String

Path = "D:\folder1\folder2\Projects\The FILES\theFILES\"FileName1"\

FileName1 = Range("B6")
FileName2 = Range("A1")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & FileName2 & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to add path value into cell and then file should be saved on that path or any thing else ?

Comment: If you are finding the filenames are not working, maybe you are just missing `.value` . `FileName1 = Range("B6").value`___you also missing quotes around the path name.

Comment: Move the `FileName1= ...` lines at the start, then change to `Path = "D:\folder1\folder2\Projects\The FILES\theFILES\" & FileName1 & "\"`
`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= Path & FileName2 & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` and it should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Answer to stated question**

```
Path = "D:\folder1\folder2\Projects\The FILES\theFILES\" & FileName1 & "\"
```

Also see ***additional feedback*** and ***corrected code*** for other feedback.

---

**Long Explanation to Answer**

When you have assign values to a string variable, the most commen way of doing so, is like this:

```
string = "This is my string value."
```

However, you may often see in code with a fairly long string, syntax such as in the following code, to allow all the text to fit on the development screen without scrolling:

```
string = "This is my really, really, really long string value. I am making this " _
    & "as long as I can, while also having something to write."
```

If you eliminated the `_`, and moved everything to one line, it would read like so:

```
string = "This is my really, really, really long string value. I am making this " & "as long as I can, while also having something to write."
```

Note that any string being assigned to a variable can be broken up in such a manner:

```
string = "This is" & " my " & "string value."

' Returns the same result as:
string = "This is my string value."
```

Furthermore, if I have a string variable, `str_val = " my "`, I could then use substitution to write the above sample as:

```
string = "This is" & str_val & "string value."
```

---

**Additional feedback**

Currently, the order of your code (see ***original code*** below) is:

1. Define variables
2. Assign value to path
3. Assign value to FileName1
4. Assign value to FileName2
5. Save File

Unfortunately, this following this order means that at step 2), the value of `FileName1` is a null string, `""`, as it hasn't been assigned a value yet.

Therfore, the order you should be following is:

1. Define variables
2. Assign value to FileName1
3. Assign value to FileName2
4. Assign value to path
5. Save File

---

**Additional variables in string**

There was an answer temporarily posted by @Davesexcel (then changed) which assumed that the `folder1` and `folder2` in your string were also variables. I attached ***alternative code*** for if that really is the case.

---

**Original Code**

```
Dim Path As String
Dim FileName1 As String
Dim FileName2 As String

Path = "D:\folder1\folder2\Projects\The FILES\theFILES\"FileName1"\

FileName1 = Range("B6")
FileName2 = Range("A1")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & FileName2 & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

---

**Corrected Code**

```
Dim Path As String
Dim FileName1 As String
Dim FileName2 As String

FileName1 = Range("B6")
FileName2 = Range("A1")

Path = "D:\folder1\folder2\Projects\The FILES\theFILES\" & FileName1 & "\"    

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & FileName2 & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

---

**Alternative Code**

```
Dim Path As String
Dim FileName1 As String
Dim FileName2 As String

FileName1 = Range("B6")
FileName2 = Range("A1")

Path = "D:\" & folder1 & "\" & folder2 & "\Projects\The FILES\theFILES\" & FileName1 & "\"    

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & FileName2 & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

Answer (score 3):

You dropped some ampersand signs, also you must assign the value of the variables before you use them:

```
Dim Path As String
Dim FileName1 As String
Dim FileName2 As String

FileName1 = Range("B6").Value
FileName2 = Range("A1").Value

Path = "D:\folder1\folder2\Projects\The FILES\theFILES\" & FileName1 & "\"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & FileName2 & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

Answer (score 1):

The code runs line by line, you need to have the correct line first.

```
Dim Path As String
Dim FileName1 As String
Dim FileName2 As String

FileName1 = Range("B6").Value
FileName2 = Range("A1")
 Path = "D:\folder1\folder2\Projects\The FILES\theFILES\" & FileName1 & "\"
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:
    Path = "D:\folder1\folder2\Projects\The FILES\theFILES\"FileName1"\

... because it contains 3 " marks. I'm not sure what your actual path is supposed to be, because path names within the operating system won't include " characters anyway. However in a VBA string assignment, the string must be enclosed between only two " characters:

"like this"

If you need to include the " character literally within a string, then you must double up the quote. So for example to assign a string to a variable which reads 'This string contains a " character', you would need to write:

```
Str = "This string contains a "" character"
```

Notice the doubling.

Check your strings, and try again.