# How do I give the address of a cell to the vlookup function in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

```
sub function1()
    Do While cells(i,4)<>"" 'Loop till value exists in column
        if cells(i,2)>0 Then ' If we have a positive value
            cells(i,5).formula="=vlookup(cells(i,3).address(0,0),table,2,true)' Adding context
        end if ' Lookup the required column value
    i=i+1
    Loop 'Try to give address of a cell into vlookup
```

Comment: C" & i  & " should do it

Comment: You may also find this answer I wrote (about including variables in string values), helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50376209/9259306

Comment: You can alsu use R1C1 referencing: `cells(i,5).formulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC3,table,2,true)"`

Comment: Expanding on @Rory 's comment for those unfamiliar with RC notation: Using `RC3` tells the formula to look in the third column of the same row as the cell holding the formula.

Comment: The problem I have is the fact that my code is not going to be RC3. It is going to be RiC3 where i is an integer that varies over every iteration. The VBA simply does not accept the variable even though I check its value in the watch tab.

Comment: @Nightclaw then you probably want to use the relative version of the RC notation. Instead of this: `cells(i,5).formula="=vlookup(cells(i,3).address(0,0),table,2,true)` use `cells(i,5).FormulaR1C1="=vlookup(RC[-2],table,2,true)`. This tells Excel to substitute (for the RC) whichever cell is 2 columns to the left of the cell the formula is being put into. If i = 3, then `cells(1,5)` --> `E3` and `=vlookup(RC[-2],table,2,true)` --> `=vlookup("C3",table,2,true)`. If i = 7, then `=vlookup(RC[-2],table,2,true)` --> `=vlookup("C7",table,2,true)`. And so on....